# How to find td element id with value x?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find exactly that td row which contains value priview '2'

I know the td row first half id, but it is dynamic:  `MovementNumber_M_*` (Where `*` can be from 1 to Milion)

So need to search all rows from `MovementNumber_M_1` to `MovementNumber_M_9999` which contains `MovementNumber_M_*.value=2` and returning directly that td row id which contained that value.

Can you help me? Thanks in advice.

Right and helpfull answers guaranteed ;)

//EDIT

```
   function DgIdOnClick (e,r){  
var MovementNumber = document.getElementById(e).value;

//alert('MovementNumber: '+MovementNumber+' Type :'+r);

    var result = $('[id^="MovementNumber_M_"][value='+MovementNumber+']');
    result.each(function(){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    });
 }
```

OK value=1 is for init and thats why are alerting all rows but if value is 2 then jq is not finding him WHY ?
The function  DgIdOnClick is inicialized @

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {  
    var SecondDiagnosis=$( "span[id^='lov_Dg2Id_D_']" );
    var SpanBlock2=SecondDiagnosis.find('a');
    var eventH2=SpanBlock2.attr( "onclick" );
    SpanBlock2.attr("onclick", "DgIdOnClick(document.getElementById('MovementNumber_D_'+parentElement.getAttribute('id').substring(12)).id,2);"+eventH2);

    var FirstDiagnosis=$( "span[id^='lov_DgId_D_']" );
    var SpanBlock=FirstDiagnosis.find('a');
    var eventH=SpanBlock.attr( "onclick" );
    SpanBlock.attr("onclick", "DgIdOnClick(document.getElementById('MovementNumber_D_'+parentElement.getAttribute('id').substring(11)).id,1);"+eventH);
});
```

function DgIdOnClick is on other .js file

If i am alerting IN     DgIdOnClick   alert(document.getElementById('MovementNumber_M_2').value)//MovementNumber_M_2 Then value is 2 but jq is not founding it

Comment: can you share a html sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This alerts the ID's of each row containing that value

```
var result = $('[id^="MovementNumber_M_"][value="2"]');
result.each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q8QaG/

Update:

This alerts the id of all inputs with the value of 2, even on input update

```
$("#button").click(function(){

$('[id^="MovementNumber_M_"]').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 2){
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
    }
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q8QaG/3/

Comment: Perfect this is working only now o am getting a huge problem :(
@ Form even if  I change the values they stay. Are some posibilities to read the actual value ? In input field real value is 3 but jq found 1
id="MovementNumber_M_1002" value="1" It seems liek my system BUG

Comment: It's not a bug, it depends on when you execute your code. In my example the code is executed once, when the page is loaded.
You want to execute this code on a change event, or maybe even on a specified button click.

Comment: The code is executed on onclick event I looked @ elements panel values on row are not changing :@ :(

Comment: How are you changing your values? Could you post your code in a fiddle?

Comment: It is still missing your HTML. If `MovementNumber` is alerting `2` in your code, and it is not finding it in the code followed after that, than apparantly they are not targeting the same element.
If you could recreate your situation in a fiddle I can fix the code there.

Comment: I got a huge Framefork who is generating HTML so it is not so simple.
The argument MovementNumber in DgIdOnClick are 2 so  if getElementById('MovementNumber_M_2') are returning 2 Why jq are not returning it ? Big Thanks yo You For help i am not in friends with .js and jq so I estimate that ;)

Comment: Because apparantly MovementNumber and the value of the targeted row is not the same.
Does your source look similair to the one I provided in the fiddle?
My guess is that you are referring to <tr> value which isn't a verified attribute, but you actualy mean the content of <tr> in stead of the value. But I can't be sure about this guess unless you provide some HTML.

Comment: No All is OK if argument is '1' that jq alert are returning massive with id's  because for all rows default value even in the elements window are showed '1' but if the argument is 2 then jq is not returning  but the select(getElement....) are.. Maybe are some posibilities to remake that jq search var result = $('input[id^="MovementNumber_M_"][value='+MovementNumber+']'); that in [value='+MovementNumber+']'); are used some getElement... ?

Comment: Please see the link http://postimg.org/image/tupgcfttv/
 Here you  can see that i have value='1' for each input field but really above you see that real input value is 3 if i select with (getElement...value) then value is corect

Comment: That is because the value is not updated yet. Simple typing a new input does not change the value in the source code.
This is however a different question than your original one, so to prevent these comments from going on for ever, I suggest you open a new question regarding this particular problem.

Comment: I dont want to open a new discusion for the same problem, maybe there is some simple way how to resolve this issue ? Thanks !

Comment: It's not exactly the same problem, but I think my updated code should work in your case. See the updated fiddle, you can change the input fields to 2, click the button and they are also alerted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of [**Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
 var myElement= $("[id^='MovementNumber_M_'][value=2]");
```

As per comment, if you need id use `attr()`

```
 var myElementId = $("[id^='MovementNumber_M_'][value=2]").attr('id');
```

Comment: This 
     var myId= $('[id^=MovementNumber_M_]'[value=2]);

Are returning: object Object :( but needed id

Comment: @Speakwithsystem, Use `var myElementId = $("[id^='MovementNumber_M_'][value=2]").attr('id');` here I have use `attr()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#TableID').find('td').filter(':contains("SOME_TEXT")');
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous 2 answers have the string encoding similarly incorrect.  This should be it:

```
$('[id^="MovementNumber_M_"][value="2"]');
```

Comment: Yes! But the returned value is not a ID but: Object object